# how to insert 2 items into a table as 2 rows

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I know I'm not supposed to write my own insert statements. But I couldn't find how to do that with Oracle Apex built-in DML option.

I have a page with 2 text field items:

```
P1_ITEM_01
P2_ITEM_02
```

I have a table

```
create table mos.items (str varchar2(20));
```

I want to insert above 2 items' values into my table *mos.items* when I submit the page, as 2 rows.

q1. How can I loop the insert action?

q2. If I must write an insert statement, I'm thinking to name my items in a certain way then select them with `LIKE 'P1_ITEM%'` from **APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS** and create a loop for each item. Is it the right approach?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be supposed to write your insert statements? The built in DML processes only work for basic use cases, you will often need your own custom DML code.

Comment: honestly, most of the time I give up and start hand crafting my own processes. but experienced apex developers here usually advice otherwise. perhaps it's just my misreadings :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way - from my point of view - is to create your own process which will

```
insert into items (str) values (:P1_ITEM_01);
insert into items (str) values (:P1_ITEM_02);
```

Anything else is probably possible, but almost certainly more complex than it should be.